# Creating a custom slider using jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, slider

I am trying to create a custom slider with two handles using jQuery UI. The problem is that the right handle is moving out of the container.

I know the problem, the reason being the fact that the handles are positioned using the `left` CSS property and since the width of the handles is more than one pixel, the right handle moves out of the container.

I don't want to use the default slider UI provided by jQuery and that's why I am fighting with this.

The code is uploaded on JSBin - http://jsbin.com/egoca/edit, copied here for prosperity:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var end = parseInt($('#slider_range_slide').attr('minvalue'), 10); 
  var start  = parseInt($('#slider_range_slide').attr('maxvalue'), 10); 

  $('#slider_bar').slider({ 
    min: 0, 
    max: 100, 
    range: true, 
    values: [0, 100], 
    animate: true, 
    slide: function(e, ui) { 
      var left = $('#slider_bar').slider('values', 0); 
      var right = $('#slider_bar').slider('values', 1); 
      $(".slide_dis_l").css("width", left+"%"); 
      $(".slide_dis_r").css("width", (100 - right)+"%"); 
      $("#slider_handle_left").css("left", left+"%"); 
      $("#slider_handle_right").css("right", (100 - right)+"%"); 
      var from = start + (left / 100) * (end - start); 
      var to = (right / 100) * (end - start); 
      $('#price_slider_display').text(from + " to " + to); 
    } 
  }); 
});
```

Any help in fixing this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to have to live with a simple fix unless you want to redevelop the entire thing with a lot of added (and unnecessary) complexity.  Even the [jQuery UI sliders](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/) overlap the left and right boundaries.

The best way to solve this is to apply a negative left-margin that's half the width of the handles as [demonstrated here](http://jsbin.com/egoca/186/edit).